# Preventing bash tab completion of an environment variable with a FS path value from removing the environment variable name

Tags: bash, environment-variables, path, command-line-interface

Friends,

I am using GNU bash as my shell on Linux:

```
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.2.45(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
$
```

It acts very strangely when I am setting an environment variable with a FS path as its value.

Say I want to add /opt/database/bin to the front of PATH.

I start by typing in:

```
$ export PATH=/o
```

Then I press the tab key on my keyboard.

But instead of completing the path to /opt, it deletes the PATH= part! Instead, I get:

```
$ export /opt/
```

That is, of course, extremely useless to me and very aggravating! I am then required to add in the environment variable name manually, which is not at all what I wish to be doing!

I wanted it to complete it to this:

```
$ export PATH=/opt/
```

Then I can complete the rest of the path using minimal typing and the tab key.

Is there any way that I can get it to not delete the environment variable, and to act in a sensible way that helps make me productive to the max?

Comment: I tried than on a few versions of Bash including 3.2.25, 4.0.33, 4.1.2, 4.2.28 and 4.2.37  and I don't see that behavior. It works for me as you'd expect. Do you have [Bash-Completion](http://bash-completion.alioth.debian.org) or any other completion functions in effect? Also, were you doing completion with `export PATH=$PATH:/o` instead of what you indicated? What distribution of Linux?

Comment: @Dennis, you are my savior! I did not even realize that Bash-Completion existed, and I did not realize that I had it installed on my Debian! After removing the bash-completion 1:2.0-1 package it is working as I expected it to. Many thanks, sir!

Comment: I'll enter it as an answer and you can mark it accepted (and upvote it too, if you like).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try disabling  [Bash-Completion](http://bash-completion.alioth.debian.org/).

Your `PATH` completion works for me, however, on systems using Bash-Completion. You might try un-installing and re-installing it to see if it works. I find the functionality it provides too useful to give up.

Answer (score 2):

disabling Bash-Completion altogether has probably been an overkill. It is a very useful and productive feature.

The breakage such as you describe is usually caused by specific bash completion configuration scripts that lie in `/etc/bash_completion.d/`, installed by third party `.deb` packages.

I had the exact same problem on Ubuntu, and in my case the culprit turned out to be the   `/etc/bash_completion.d/npm` script installed by the `npm` Debian package (containing the package manager for Node.js).

I've just moved the `npm` script out of `/etc/bash_completion.d/` - problem solved, and useful Bash Completion functionality preserved.

Comment: BTW, I've reported the issue in this particular script:

https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/4530